# What is "column independent code"?

Tags: c, fortran, programming-languages, computer-science, fortran90

*User Notes on FORTRAN Programming*, chapter 1-2 ([Comparison of FORTRAN and C](https://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/ch1-2.html)), says:

> Fortran 90 supports useful features of C (**column independent code**,
>   pointers, dynamic memory allocation, etc) and C++ (operator 
>   overloading, primitive objects).

What does the term *"column independent code"* mean?

Comment: Never heard of it. Maybe this is known under a different name? Read on, maybe you'll find what it means, so we can provide the common phrase from the description.

Comment: I don't know FORTRAN but as I remember, it used to require you to write your program statements in strictly defined columns, whereas in C you can indent lines whatever you like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Fortran 77 lines were divided into sections by columns and each part of your code had to go into a specific section. Specifically for non-comment lines , the first 5 columns would either contain that line's label or be blank if the line had no label. Column 6 would contain an arbitrary non-space character if the line was a continuation of a previous line or be left blank otherwise. And columns 7 through 72 would contain the actual statement to be executed on that line. Comment lines would contain a "c" in the first column and the rest of the line would not matter.

In Fortran 90 and C (and most other languages) the columns don't matter. You can write any part of your code at any column you please. That's almost certainly what's meant as "column independent code" in the post you cited.

This concept is more commonly known as free-form code.

Comment: Right.  Remember that Fortran and Cobol date from the days of punch cards, so formatting was very rigid.

Comment: Statements appear from column 7: column 6 would be for continuation marks.  Columns _may_ matter in Fortran 90, it's just that Fortran 90 _allows_ them not to.  [That is, Fortran 90 introduced free-form, but fixed-form source is valid even in Fortran 2008.]

Comment: @francescalus Right, fixed the bit about statements starting at column 6. Thanks.

Comment: @Olaf free-form is the official term for the source form according to the Fortran standard.

Comment: @VladimirF: I don't know Fortran, but the term I used is common for PLs in general. But there are certainly other phrases, too.

Comment: note in free form fortran the line end still *does delimit* the code whereas in c variants line ends are essentially ignored.

Comment: "Column 6 would contain an arbitrary if the line was a continuation" There seems to be a word missing.

Comment: As a final bit of pedantry, if column 6 in fixed-form source contains a zero the line isn't a continuation.

Comment: Many Fortran compilers will interpret any character in the first column as a comment. For example this current Fortran [program](http://data.giss.nasa.gov/pub/gistemp/SBBX_to_nc.f) uses `!` as the comment character.